# How to Implement Paypal DoDirectPayment in PHP?

Tags: paypal

Please suggest me a PHP Class to implement Paypal DoDirectPayment with ease. I require the PAYMENTACTION = Authorization and Sale.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a good reference.](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/05/getting-started-with-the-paypal-api/) Scroll down to the DoDirectPayment section.  Note that you'd have to set the "PAYMENTACTION" to Authorization first.  Then you can capture the AUTHORIZATIONID in the response and run again with PAYMENTACTION=Sale.

[See this section of the PayPal API as well](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_WPDPGettingStarted#id66d4030b-3adb-4da7-8782-35f35fcf0cd7)

Comment: Both the links are dead.